# What is the position embedding code?

Tags: nlp, embeddings, deep-learning

https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/modeling.py#L491-L520

The code of BERT is one of the implementation. But it is not what I need.

I search a lot but can not judge.

But where is the code which seems uses `cos` and `sin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code implemented by TensorFlow:

Implementation 1:

[image: position embedding]
[image: position embedding]

Implementation 2:

[image: position embedding]